# woo commerce and creating buyer groups on a WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I am creating a website which is going to be a normal e-commerce responsive website using WordPress.

I have a request from the client and I needed some clarification on the subject.

For 3 different clients who log in using their usernames and passwords they want all the commodity prices on the website to change.

To make it clearer:-
Price of a bottle of wine is $10 and this is on display to users who have not logged in. When a specific user logs in the price of same bottle of wine goes to $8 .The changes take place throughout the website for all the products.

I hope this makes sense. I have been using woocommerce but I haven't been able to find a plug-in that would let me do this. Is there a plugin or a way to do this. Please help.

Comment: What you are describing is called wholesale pricing. Please try researching that.

Comment: why would someone give the question a negative rating???

Comment: Because you're asking for a plugin recommendation which is off topic.

Comment: are you serious !!
how is a plugin off topic ?
the answer given below refers to plugins. The question is asking for help, if I knew that there was no plugin for this then I wouldn't be asking the question. 
you need to calm down and chill my friend
you might be a senior programmer or something big in your own world but don't forget that you were a beginner once and it takes time to learn. 
Grow up!

Comment: Please review what is considered [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to do this, you can customize your woocommerce plugin and also use a plugin, I would chose to use a plugin.

There are many plugins that allows to change products' rates as per users' role. I would suggest you to use [Woocommerce Role Pricing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-pricing/screenshots/) plugin.

Comment: but on this site anyone can make an account and but so every user coming on the website will have the same role assigned to them but let's say 3 out of these 100 users are supposed to see a different pricing.
How would that work, is there a plugin for that ?